# After all, finally etc

Tags: grammar

Is it possible to use, for example: "finally, after all", to express impatience or annoyance like the word already?

Can you tell me where they gone after all?
Stop asking me stupind questions ***after all***!

Can you shut up ***finally/after all***?

Comment: [correction: where **they've** gone?] Please look up terms and/or do research before posting.

Comment: I would say no to "after all". Not sure where you've got this use of "after all" from. Chambers has this as meaning "When everything is taken into account" or "In spite of everything".

Comment: By no means all native Anglophones use appended ***already*** to indicate "impatience or annoyance". Lots of people tack it on the same as many Canadians end utterances with ***Eh*** (but *not* as a question; like BrE ***innit***, it has no "meaning"). I don't know the history of it, but appended ***already*** is so much more common among American Jews than the population at large that I assume it corresponds to some equivalent usage in Yiddish. Personally, I *never* use it, and even after countless exposures, I *still* think it's a bit "odd".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot use those words to replace *already*. It would be incorrect to use *after all* like that and it would not sound natural to use *finally* like that.

You can attach *after all* to a sentence to signal that the sentence supports a previous statement. For example, "The word usage you suggested doesn't work, but it is good that you asked. *After all*, you can't learn without asking questions."